# Django/Python convert string to Model filter with '=' in result

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm working on writing `test_templates` so that I can very quickly write my tests, as I realized I was duplicating the same code with different variables. But I've run into a problem:

```
# path of view
# '/app/view/path/'
view_name = 'service:create_employee_profile'

# valid field values to test form success.
valid_values = {
    'first_name': 'First',
    'last_name': 'Last',
}

# Search criteria for Model 'get' and 'filter'
# Model.objects.get(field=value)
# Model.objects.get(eval(model_criteria))
model_criteria = 'first_name="First"'

"""
TESTS: Submitting forms
"""
# TEST: View saves valid object.
def test_view_saves_valid_object(self):
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse(view_name), valid_values)

    self.assertTrue(Model.objects.filter(eval(model_criteria)).exists())
```

I thought I was set with `eval()`, until I quickly discovered that it doesn't like `=`. I tried using 2 different variables for `'first_name="First"'`, but a Model will never find a field out of a `variable='field_name'`.

These templates help me test multiple views with adding just a little information to them, and since more than 1 test in the template requires retrieving an instance of the model I am trying to set a variable at the top that will run all associated tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary instead:

```
model_criteria = {'first_name': "First"}
```

Just unpack it when you pass it as `filter()` argument using `**`:

```
self.assertTrue(Model.objects.filter(**model_criteria).exists())
```